# Is it correct to write "junior year" in my email signature?

Tags: email

I am a third year undergraduate student in a four-year course. The last year my email signature was of the form:

[Name],

sophomore,

[Institute Name]

This year however, I doubt whether using "junior year undergraduate" instead of "sophomore" would be right. Moreover, I and my classmates generally do not write "Class of" because the students around my area are enrolled in degrees of varying durations, which is quite confusing when the recipient wants to know how many years I have completed so far and how many years are left to complete my degree.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that adding "sophomore" to one's e-mail signature was customary, but other times, other places, other customs!  Will you write "senior" next year?  If you will write "senior" next year, and wrote "sophomore" last year, why not "junior" this year?

Comment: Are you in the US? Assuming so, I think if "Sophomore, X Institution" is widely understood where you are, then "Junior, X Institution" would be, too. The meaning of junior should be clear from the fact that you're at a college/university. Editing to add that like @ab2, this is an unfamiliar practice to me, though I have seen undergraduate addresses that include the expected date of graduation, so I can imagine some utility to it.

Comment: @ab2 Not all students use this kind of signature in my university. People generally like to write sophomore in their second year but change to "pre-final(third) year" the next year, which I find too long and not-so-clean for a signature. Moreover, not many have to really care about the recipient knowing about their degree's duration with respect to their current year at college, but I currently manage a few tasks in which I have to constantly mail folks from industry/academia around the world and so it gets important for me.

Comment: @nedibes No I'm outside the US, but people do understand these terms here. Moreover as mentioned in my earlier comment, I also get to deal with mailing people in America and countries like Singapore where it is common. I suppose I can use "junior" now, but wouldn't it be weird to have something like: John, Junior, [department], [university] ? Just because the term "junior" has several different connotations in English, in comparison to "sophomore" which can be readily understood real quick.

Comment: Then think about saying "junior year".   I can understand why students would not like to say just "junior".  Junior is used in many different ways, usually meaning someone in a relatively lowly position -- junior executive, junior assistant, junior member of the staff,  Tom Smith, Jr (my father's son) and so on.

Comment: Just be careful if you're writing to Brits. Here, junior school finishes at age 11; school of any form finishes by age 17-18; "sophomore" is meaningless. If I heard the expression, I would assume that "junior year" at university means the first year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tom Smith,
Junior, University of X

will be understood by anyone worth your attention to mean that you are in your junior year at the University of X.

If there is anything ambiguous about the name of your school, so that the reader will not instantly recognize it as a school, then

Tom Smith,
Junior-year student, XYZ

would be better.

You may be reluctant to use the word Junior because junior is so often used to mean "relatively lowly", as in junior staff, junior faculty, junior associate, but again, anyone worth your time and attention knows that juniors are third year students.

Obligatory Reference [Wikipedia, junior, education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junior_(education))

> A junior is a student in their third year of study (generally
>   referring to high school or college/university study). Juniors
>   are considered upperclassman

To cover all the bases, if your e-mail sounds like you could be a junior in high school, you are in deep trouble. :)  I don't think that is the case from the wording of your question.